# Access numpy matrix element using list of unknown length

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

So I have an numpy.array of unknown dimension and I generate a list of indices in order to access a specific element within the matrix.

If I knew it was a 3x3 matrix I'd simply access:

```
A[1,2,3]
```

or something similar. However, I'm generating the [1,2,3] as a list and then need to access the matrix element using that list. If I do

```
A[List]
```

which is essentially doing

```
A[[1,2,3]]
```

I obviously just get slices from the 1,2,3 elements in the first dimension

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make your list into a tuple:

```
>>> A = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
>>> A
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
>>> A[1,2,3]
23
>>> A[(1,2,3)]
23
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> A[tuple(b)]
23
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ... I thought I'd tried that but evidently not!

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list to a tuple. Then it works fine.

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> A
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> A[1, 2]
6
>>> indices = [1,2]
>>> A[indices]
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> A[tuple(indices)]
6
```